# log4j2.xml path Configuration

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I created maven project from console, added dependencies and so on. I want to configure my logging with log4j2.xml file. I found on FAQ [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location), but when i put `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml` in cmd it doesn't work. What should I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said it is a maven project, You can simply place the `log4j.xml` under `src/main/resources` directory. It shall be able to read from there.

Comment: I put it there and it seems maven 'can see that', bacause it shows `[INFO] Copying 1 resource`, but it doesn't work. I'll check out if every other thing is ok, and I let you know.